# Angular: re-using textContent as Input attribute causes error

Tags: angular, angular5

I made a directive wrapper around [strokeText.js](https://github.com/inorganik/strokeText.js) that adds a stroke (or "outline") to text via the canvas api. In some cases I am stroking dynamic text, which changes based on user input. So I set it up like this:

```
<h2 strokeText [textContent]="totalPoints"></h2>
```

My directive implements `OnChanges` to react to changes to the bound input `totalPoints`, so that it can re-stroke the text:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import * as StrokeText from 'stroketext.js';

@Directive({
    selector: '[strokeText]'
})
export class StrokeTextDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
    stroked: any;

    @Input('strokeText') params: Array<any>;
    @Input() textContent: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {   }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.createStrokeText();
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log('changes', changes);
        this.createStrokeText();
    }

    private createStrokeText() {
        const thick = this.params[0] ? parseFloat(this.params[0]) : 3;
        const color = this.params[1] ? this.params[1] : 'white';

        if (this.stroked) { this.stroked.reset(); }
        this.stroked = new StrokeText(this.el.nativeElement);
        this.stroked.stroke(thick, color);

    }
}
```

However this immediately throws `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9912)`. Even if I comment out all the strokeText stuff, I still get the error. (Angular v5.2.0)

StrokeText.js doesn't have a name property, nor does this directive. I've gotten this error before with Angular, when dealing with bound properties and it seems to be an Angular bug.

I don't know if it doesn't like me reusing the built-in `textContent` directive, or if something else is wrong. The net result is that it doesn't display any text inside the h2, even though `totalPoints` is set. I know because I can do

```
<h2 strokeText>{{ totalPoints }}</h2>
```

and it works fine, it just doesn't react to changes, and the stroke doesn't update.

**Update**: simply removing The Input property textContent also fixes the error, but again it can't react to changes.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jALd0GQhPSXOLrnJMO7W?p=preview

Comment: Tried to get this plunker going.. https://plnkr.co/edit/50ZkUUVtYdUuFndsCGma?p=preview

Comment: @AdamCox I added a plunker link

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not let you re-use built-in Angular directives as attributes for your own directives.

You have to pass the same property to a differently-named attribute, like this:

```
<h1 strokeText [textToStroke]="totalPoints" [textContent]="totalPoints"></h1>
```

Then you can use `ngOnChanges` as I did in my question to react to changes. Demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wJM9InkTxdDn3GIVS4yy?p=preview

Side note, upgrading Angular from 5.2.0 to 5.2.4 made the error go away, and the directive just wouldn't be rendered when trying to reuse the built-in directive as an attribute of my own directive.